# someone help me at avatar command

Tags: javascript, discord.js, avatar

I'm not good at programming, and I want to have a command that takes the mentioned user avatar. I don't know how to make this let correctly. So far, this is what I tried:

```
let avatar = message.mentions.users.first.displayAvatarURL({format: 'png'});
```

Comment: Please share the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Collection#first`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) is a method, so use this instead:

```js
let avatar = message.mentions.users.first().displayAvatarURL({format: 'png'});
```

---

> I dont know how to make this let correctly

Next time, please include any errors that you had or describe the unintended behaviour. See the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on the help centre.